# Is body wearable antenna same as directional antenna?

Tags: rf, antenna

I find that some product use a body wearable antenna, which is used as a directional antenna.
See pki "direction finder" here using directional antenna:
http://www.pki-electronic.com/products/interception-and-monitoring-systems/gsm-direction-finder/

But I don't understand how such antenna can be directional antenna, it is not directed to anywhere as far as I understand.

Another image of body antenna:
http://www.pharad.com/330-380-mhz-wearable-antenna.html

Comment: Where do you get the idea that those two items have anything to do with one another?  One uses antennas, the other is an antenna.  That is it.  The antenna isn't even for a range that would work with the other thing.

Comment: List of things I really don't want to wear close to my body: 1) burlap bags, 2) GSM antennas.

Answer (score 1):

If the antenna is truly isotropic then the body may become the radiator under where it is attached and the surface the radiator above where it is exposed.  Where it is attached and how may affect the results thru the body and thus be different from the results alone inside a chamber.

Whereas Vertical dipole antenna on your hat radiates like a donut omnidirectional in the horizontal plane it might look like a lightning rod or just a rubber ducky on on your wingnut hat.  In Theory a dipole has no gain looking down both ends of the pole and increases to 2dB. THis antenna has a loss from -6 to 0 dB in both elevation and azimuth which standalone is fairly isotropic and less noticeable but less gain than a vertical dipole. or monopole. (1/2 or 1/4wave)

So  if you’re only looking to improve cell signals for one carrier, go with a **directional** antenna with high gain over a narrow elevation but omnidirectional for azimuth. It's more powerful and doesn't take much work to find the general direction of the cell tower.

If you’re looking to boost all the major carriers, go with the **omni**. And especially if you already have pretty good signal but building material is the main problem obstructing your 3G & 4G signal, then this is a winner, too.